# convert array to jquery ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

Hi im trying to convert my Array with ids in an array with #id.
But i only get one return and i dont know why? I am 100% that im not using the return statement right but i cant get it work

```
        function convortToJquery(e) {

            for(var i = 0;i <= e.length;i++){
                var jqueryArray = [];

                if(!e[i]){
                    return jqueryArray;
                }else{
                    jqueryArray = "#"+e[i];
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

```
       var jArrayText = convortToJquery(textWord);
```

Comment: what are you passing to this function?

Comment: ...and what's `textWord` then?

Comment: Array [ "Bacon", "ipsum", "dolor", "amet", "andouille", "chicken", "picanha", "burgdoggen,", "short", "ribs", ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `textWord` is an array of strings, your function is creating a *new* array for every entry. You only want to create a new array once. Also strongly recommend not using the pattern of going past the end of the array and relyingon `!e[i]` to decide to return from the function. There's no need for that kind of thing, and it introduces a maintenance issue by being odd.

Minimal fixes to your code would look like this (but keep reading):

```
function convortToJquery(e) {
    var jqueryArray = [];                   // Do this once at the beginning
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {    // <, not <=
        jqueryArray[i] = "#" + e[i];        // Put the entry in the array
    }
    return jqueryArray;
}
```

**But**: This is exactly what [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for:

```
function convortToJquery(array) {
    return array.map(function(entry) {
        return "#" + entry;
    });
}
```

`map` calls the callback you give it once for each entry in the array, building a new array from what the callback returns.

In an ES2015+ environment (or with transpiling), it's rather more concise:

```
function convortToJquery(array) {
    return array.map(e => "#" + e);
}
```

Or if you can use `const` (or `let`) and a function expression instead of a full-on `function` function (which has things this doesn't need):

```
const convortToJquery = array => array.map(e => "#" + e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is incorrect. Inside a for loop there will be always a value for `e[i]`. So you should return after the loop completion. Also initialize the array at top so that it wont be initiated to empty in every loop

```js
function convortToJquery(e) {
  var jqueryArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {  
      jqueryArray.push("#" + e[i]);
  }
  return jqueryArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is manipulate each element of array

```
function convortToJquery(e) {
  return  e.map(function(item){
    return '#'+item
    });
}
```

```js
var textWord = [1,2,3,4];
function convortToJquery(e) {
      return  e.map(function(item){
        return '#'+item
        });
    } 
    
    document.write(convortToJquery(textWord));
```

Answer (score -2):

you are not pushing anything into the array

jqueryArray.push( "#"+e[i];)